# Question about the imaginary unit

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As we know, we define
$$\sqrt{-1}=i$$
But I always wondered, what about $\sqrt{i}$? As far as i can see, it is not an integer power of $i$. Every odd root has a solution in an integer power of $i$, but I can't find one for my question. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Oh, I didn't (saw)see that question. I will also vote to close for duplicate.

Comment: @chubakueno "*...didn't see...*"

Comment: As a spanish native, I hope you understand me, @PeterTamaroff :)

Comment: Of course, but one should always strive for correctness.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$. The square of this is $i$. It is a fact that the complex numbers are algebraically closed, and so in particular, every number has a square root.

Comment: "Recall" is a strong term - it implies a person might have forgotten something, when, given the question, it is quite possible that the OP hasn't encountered the notion of "algebraically closed."

Comment: That is a fair point. I accidentally find myself using "recall" all the time when I shouldn't!

Comment: Didn't know about algebraic closure before asking, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Complex numbers have a nice geometric interpretation -- the complex number $a + bi$ is visualized as a point in a plane with coordinates $(a,b)$.  When you multiply two complex numbers, geometrically you just "add the angles and multiply the lengths".  With this geometric interpretation you can easily find a square root of $i$.   $\frac{1 + i}{\sqrt 2}$ works.